# My if statement won't work

Tags: python, function, file, if-statement, for-loop

This is a snippet of my code, I'm trying to make a scrabble type game but for some reason this if statement isn't working. The file I'm opening is a list of 238,000 words, the English dictionary, and tempword is predefined by an input which is passed over to this function. So here I'm trying to have the tempword compared to every word in the file, but when it runs through it doesn't add to the tally even though I know that word is in the list. Any thoughts?

```
def checkvalidword(tempword):
    tally = 0
    file = open("words.txt")
    for x in file:
        if x == tempword:
            tally+=1
            print("Added to the tally")
```

Comment: is there only one word in each line of your file?

Comment: Yes, there is only one word per line and the last line is a blank space

Comment: you could add `file = open("words.txt").read().split(\n)`

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! The solution has been found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are reading lines from the file each line ends with '\n'

Try doing this instread.

```
def checkvalidword(tempword):
tally = 0
file = open("words.txt")
for x in file:
    if x.strip() == tempword:
        tally+=1
        print("Added to the tally")
```

Notice the x.strip()

Comment: Do you think I should say x.strip('\n')

Comment: You can,  but by default it strips all types of whitespace from beginning and the end of the string.

Comment: This worked, Thanks man!

Comment: I have to wait 6 mins :\

Answer (score 0):

In order to compare the values, you should be using `.strip()` with `if` as:

```
if x.strip() == 'abc':
```

Because at the end of each line, there is a new line character `\n` present. You may verify it by printing the [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) value of `x` as:

```
print repr(x)
```

You will see something like:

```
'abc\n'
```

It is even better to use `file.readlines()` as it splits the content of file based on `\n`. Hence you won't have to explicitly `strip` the new line character.